# Edit/delete not working symfony 3

Tags: symfony, crud

My edit/delete was working and as I continued to work on my project it stopped working somewhere along the way. I get this message when I try to edit or delete.

"No route found for "DELETE /shrubs/1/edit": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, POST, HEAD)"

I thought the controller handled this or do I need something in the routing.yml too?

I have this in my controller:

```
/**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Shrubs entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="shrubs_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Shrubs $shrub)
    {
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($shrub);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ShrubsType', $shrub);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($shrub);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('shrubs_edit', array('id' => $shrub->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('shrubs/edit.html.twig', array(
        'shrub' => $shrub,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Deletes a Shrubs entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="shrubs_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Shrubs $shrub)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($shrub);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($shrub);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('shrubs_index');
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a Shrubs entity.
 *
 * @param Shrubs $shrub The Shrubs entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm(Shrubs $shrub)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('shrubs_delete', array('id' => $shrub->getId())))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

My edit page has this:

```
 <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>

    {{ form_start(delete_form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
    {{ form_end(delete_form) }}
```

If I need something for my routing.yml what would I add?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `DELETE` method in your routing, this is what the error message is saying.
You use a `DELETE` method but you only allow `GET, POST`.

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Shrubs entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="shrubs_edit")
 * @Method({"DELETE", "GET", "POST"})
*/
public function editAction(Request $request, Shrubs $shrub)
```